# Angular Error: src/app/app.component.html - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}';

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

### Spring Boot with Angular

I am trying to complete the tutorial [Spring Security and Angular](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) on the Spring website. The tutorial links to [this github page](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-angular) where it shows how to install angular into your spring application. I have gotten everything working when I hard code the greeting inside the app.component.ts file like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'client';
  greeting = {'id': 'XXX', 'content': 'Hello, World'};
}
```

I get this on my home page: [Working Angular Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hghUi.png)

My error arises when I try to use [Angular's http service](https://angular.io/guide/http#prerequisites) to pass dynamic content to the page. When I change my app.component.ts file to this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Demo';
  greeting = {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    http.get('resource').subscribe(data => this.greeting = data);
  }
}
```

Then run ng build on the CLI, I get this error: [ng build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzwPK.png)

Here is my app.component.html file:

```
<div style="text-align:center" class="container">
  <h1>
    Welcome {{title}}!
  </h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Id: <span>{{greeting.id}}</span></p>
    <p>Message: <span>{{greeting.content}}!</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my app.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my PageController.java file:

```
package com.example.auctionapp;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class PagesController {
    @RequestMapping("/resource")
    public Map<String,Object> home() {
        Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        model.put("content", "Hello, World");
    
        return model;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for an explanation!

Comment: You need to properly type your greeting or give it initial values instead of an empty object so typescript knows the shape. Like greeting = {id: '', content: ''};

Comment: @MikeOne - You're the real MVP! To add on, I did have to change http.get('resource') to http.get<any>('resource'). Thanks again and have a great day!

Answer (score -1):

please define complete url in get method. subscribe to get method should be like this:

```js
  http.get('http://localhost:8080/resource').subscribe(data => this.greeting = data);
```